Unable to obtain springboot applicationContext in test with Cucmber and Serenity
I am new to the cucumber & serenity and took reference from https://github.com/teggr/serenity-bdd-demo/tree/master/src for setting up the project.
I am using testContainer , cucmber & serenity for testing.  below is the my configuration
build.gradle
//Serenity
    testImplementation("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityVersion}")
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-spring:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-single-page-report:${serenityVersion}"
    testImplementation("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured:${serenityVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-xml'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-json'
    }
    testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine"

TestContainerConfiguration.java
public class TestContainerConfiguration {
    static MSSQLServerContainer<?> mssqlServerContainer = new MSSQLServerContainer<>("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
            .acceptLicense()
            .withInitScript("schema-it.sql");

}

RunSerenityIT.java
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test-integration/resources", tags = "", glue = "com.eod", publish = true)
public class RunSerenityIT extends TestContainerConfiguration {
    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer<?> sqlServer = TestContainerConfiguration.mssqlServerContainer;
}


EodApplicationIT.java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = EodApplicationIT.Initializer.class)
public class EodApplicationIT {
    @Before
    public void loadSpring() {
        // do nothing
    }

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {

            TestPropertyValues.of("server.port=8080", "spring.datasource.url=" + TestContainerConfiguration.mssqlServerContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + TestContainerConfiguration.mssqlServerContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + TestContainerConfiguration.mssqlServerContainer.getPassword()

            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());

        }

    }



}

Cucumber class
public class InitiateAndVerifyDataIT {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Given("Initiate data in table Table1")
    public void initiateDataInTableTable1() {

        Integer locationCount =jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1", Integer.class);
        assertThat(locationCount).isEqualTo(15);
    }

Application is starting and loading all the data.
But spring Beans are not available in InitiateAndVerifyDataIT and gives the NUllPointerException.
Below igves the nullpoint exception.
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

How can I  get spring Beans in cucumber
It works when I use testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:${cucumberVersion}" and EodApplicationIT is annotated with @CucumberContextConfiguration
What is the alternative for @CucumberContextConfiguration in serenity to load application context.
